# xmlpullparser - how to parse a tag with several elements in one?

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I got an xml with geo-coordinates which has several elements in one tag

```
  <coordinates>37.481972,55.565380,0.000000</coordinates>
```

how do I deal with them?
or do I have to simply get this as a String and then search for "," to separate this 3 numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Parse them as normal string .And later use the spilt function to convert them in to a string array